# number of array accesses in java code

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I was going through the analysis of `quick-union algorithm` in the book `Algorithms 4th ed` by sedgewick.The author gives this piece of code and comments

```
...
for(int i =0; i< N; i++){
    id[i] = i;
}
...
private int find(int p){
    while(p != id[p]){
        p = id[p];
    }
    return p;
}

public void union(int p, int q) {       
    int proot = find(p);
    int qroot = find(q);
    if (proot == qroot){
        return;
    }
    id[proot] = qroot;
    this.count--;
}
```

A worst case is considered where p,q pairs (0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4) etc are given to `union()`.The autor comments that number of array accesses for `union()` for pair `0,i` is exactly `2i+3` (note: in the book it is printed as 2i+2 but the errata says 2i+3).site 0 is at depth i and site i is at depth 0.

I tried to work this out for the call union(0,1)

this involves two `find()` calls (with 0 and 1 as inputs)and an array modification `id[proot]= qroot`

consider find(0)

The array id[] is `0,1,2,3,4..`

In the while loop , p =0

test 0 != id[0] fails since id[0]=0  .So,there is only 1 array access in find(0)

In find(1), test 1 != id[1] fails ,and thus find(1) only makes 1 array access.

then id[proot] = qroot causes only 1 array access.

In total there are 3 array accesses.

But when using the equation 2i+3 is used (for pair (0,i))

number of array accesses for pair (0,1) -> 2*1+3 = 5

I am confused.. can someone tell me where I have erred?

Comment: From the code you posted it looks like it's `2(i-1) + 3 = 2i + 1`. Perhaps he noticed that `2i+2` was off-by-1 and... accidentally increased it by 1 instead of decreasing it by 1. I usually ignore these small details after some thought unless they change later arguments/analyses. In this case, does Sedgewick use this claim to prove something else? Does it really matter if it's `2i+1` or `2i+2` or `2i+3`? If not, I would say that it's not worth sweating over this. Sometimes an off-by-1 issue can turn out to be an important nuance/misunderstanding, but it doesn't seem like that's the case here.

Comment: maybe you are right..he doesn't delve into a detailed analysis ,but says that the total number of array accesses is `~N^2`

Comment: If you mean over a `union(0, 1), union(0, 2), ..., union(0, n)` calling pattern then that sounds about right. Each `union()` is `2i+1` and summing that over `n` gives you `O(n^2)` (feel free to do the algebra and prove it to yourself or ask a separate question on math.stackexchange if you get stuck on the maths). If it were `2i+2` or `2i+3` or even `2i+10000` the complexity is still the same.

Comment: if you can convert these into an answer, I could accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My analysis seems to agree with you that both the original solution and the errata are wrong. My claim is that it will take `2(i-1) + 3` array accesses for `union(0, i)` assuming that the calling pattern is `union(0, 1), union(0, 2), ..., union(0, i)`. We can prove it by induction.

In particular we prove a stronger claim which is that `union(0, i)` takes `2(i-1 + 3` array accesses *and* the `id` array will look like at `1, 2, 3, ..., k-2, k, k, k+1, ..., N` after the `k`th `union()`. The stronger claim makes the induction clean.

In the base case, as you observed, there are three array accesses for `union(0, 1)`. At that point, by inspection, we have an array that looks like `[1, 1, 2, ..., N]` as desired. In the inductive step we've assumed that the claim holds for `1 <= j <= k` and consider the state of the `id` array at the start of the `union(0, k+1)`. At this point it will look like

```
[1, 2, 3, ..., k-2, k, k, k+1, ..., N]
```

by the induction hypothesis. At this point by inspection we have our claim. In particular, `find(0)` will take `2(k + 1 - 1)` array accesses. `find(k+1)` will take two. The assignment of `id[0] = k+1` is the last which gives us `2((k + 1) - 1) + 2 + 1 => 2((k + 1) - 1) + 3` as desired. Note that the array will also turn into

```
[1, 2, 3, ..., k-2, k-1, k+1, k+1, k+2, ..., N]
```

as we need for the induction.

The latter part you mentioned in the comments about this being `Theta(n^2)` follows from some algebra. In particular let `f(n)` be the number of array accesses from calling `union(0, 1), union(0, 2), ..., union(0, n)` where `n < N` the size of the array. Then the above claim shows that `f(n) - f(n-1) = 2(n - 1) + 1` and `f(1) = 3` (our base case). Then we have that

```
f(n) = f(n) - f(n-1) + 
       (f(n-1) - f(n-2)) + 
       (f(n-2) - f(n-3)) + 
       ... + 
       (f(2) - f(1)) + 
       f(1)
=>
f(n) = 2(n-1) + 3 +
       2(n-2) + 3 +
       2(n-3) + 3 +
       ... +
       2(1) + 3 + 
       2(0) + 3
=>
f(n) = Sum(2(i-1) + 3) from i = 1 to i = n
```

The first step is because it "telescopes" and is true by inspection. There is a nifty trick to computing arithmetic, finite progressions like this. You add the first and last elements, then the second and second-to-last elements, and so on. You'll notice they're all the same, and provably will be the same. I'll let you mess with that, but the closed form is

```
n^2 + 2
```

Showing that's `Theta(n^2)` is an "exercise left to the reader" heh. If all else fails you should see an equivalent proof in your textbook.

Oh and I mentioned above in the comments that even if it were `2i+2` or `2i+3` the proofs above wouldn't really change that much. Definitely spend time asking this question, but not hours... especially if you feel confident in your answer (by proving it as I did here, or sketching the proof in your head). There will almost guaranteed be cases where off-by-1 is super significant (there are some base cases which are actually very hard to see why they have certain values! Spending time knowing why it's 0 and not 1 can be valuable), so you have to make your own judgment. Good luck